# Python Django REST Infinite Recursion Problem

Tags: python, sql-server, django

As of late I've started working towards learning REST Api with Django Rest Framework, Cors headers, and mssql connector both for personal purposes, and for a project I'm working on. Beneath I'll include snippets of code and or the errors I got to make this easier to digest.

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Working with this project, I got close to completing a Get/Post/Put method, but once I attempted to run the server itself, it ended in an endless recursion. I've attempted to search a variety of threads but I'm quite unsure what the problem may be.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('BingeWatcherApp.urls'))
]

class Users(models.Model):
    UID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    UFName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ULName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    UEmail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 
from rest_framework import serializers
from BingeWatcherApp.models import Users

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Users
        fields=('UID', 'UFName','ULName', 'UEmail')

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.Users, name='Users'),
    path('BingeWatcherApp/', include('BingeWatcherApp.urls'))

]

def UserAPI(request, id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':
        users = Users.objects.all()
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(user_serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method =='POST':
        user_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        user_serializer=UserSerializer(data=user_data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("User Inserted Correctly", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Error. Please insert valid data.")
    elif request.method=='PUT':
        user_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        user = Users.objects.get(UID=user_data['UID'])
        user_serializer=UserSerializer(user, data=user_data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid:
            user_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Data updated successfully")
        return JsonResponse("Data update unsuccesfull. Try again.")
```

In order are the main url.py document, models.py, serializer.py, url.py within my app, and my view. Note these are all in different files, not a single file. As for the major imports I'm using Django 4.0, Django-cors-headers, DjangoRestFramework and MSSQL-Django.

If you need more information, or find the error. Let me know and I'll respond as quickly as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. Ill keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are including `BingeWatcherApp.urls` inside itself. This is what leads to the error

Comment: That's true.  What would be the correct syntax for that line in particular?

Comment: Remove it
```path('', include('BingeWatcherApp.urls'))```

Comment: If you want to have multiple apps running on different urls. You create a main app and then create sub-apps and include those urls in the main app.

Comment: I did as you recommneded, and removed the snippet of code, but instead of giving me an endless recursive error, it simply doesnt start.

Comment: NVM, I believe that issue is related to the database. Thank you for the help!